# Error when Moving File on Networked Drive

Tags: windows, windows-7, qnap

On one computer (windows 7) we get the following error when trying to move a file into a child folder which is contained on a network drive.  We have tried Admin of Domain, Making the user admin, lowering IE permissions, and still, nothing works.

To Reproduce:

1. Open networked folder in Windows Explorer
2. Drag File in `\EDI\test.txt` to `\EDI\Archive\`
3. A message pops up "These files might be harmful to your computer".
4. Click OK and it moves.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error but a security warning.

Your computer most likely does not trust on your network or just the NAS. May be because you accessed by IP.

Since you clicked "Ok", I assume you trust that device. You can disable this warnings therefore.

> - Click Start / Control Panel / Internet Options
> - Click Security tab.
> - Click Local Intranet
> - Click Sites button.
> - Click Advanced button.
> - Enter **the IP Address of the other machine or server (wildcards are allowed)** and click Add
> - Click Close, then OK, then OK again.
> - **Disconnect, and reconnect the network drive**

quoted from: [Disable “These files might be harmful to your computer” warning](https://superuser.com/a/149057/339147)